# Laravel Soap server returns procedure not present error

Tags: php, laravel, soap

Can anyone help me with an issue am having, I need to implement a SOAP server in Laravel that handles the following request:

```
<s12:Envelope xmlns:s12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>
  <s12:Body>
    <ns1:customerCustomerRepositoryV1SaveRequest xmlns:ns1='https://ecommerce.app/api/soap/web/all?services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1'>
      <customer>
        <id>999</id>
        <status>Active</status>
      </customer>
    </ns1:customerCustomerRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
  </s12:Body>
</s12:Envelope>
```

I managed to get a SOAP server running using [viewflex/zoap](https://github.com/viewflex/zoap) composer package. I got the following code in my webservices class

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\ERP;

use App\Services\ERP\Repository\CustomerRepository;

class WebServices
{
    /**
     * 
     * Update customers
     * 
     * @param array customer
     * @return array
     */
    public function customerCustomerRepositoryV1SaveRequest(array $customer)
    {
        return CustomerRepository::customer($customer[0], $customer[1]);
    }
}
```

My api.php file has the following route structure

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'soap'], function() {
    Route::get('{key}/all', [\Viewflex\Zoap\ZoapController::class, 'server']);
    Route::post('{key}/all', [\Viewflex\Zoap\ZoapController::class, 'server']);
});
```

When I perform a POST request to my SOAP Server I get the following error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <env:Body>
        <env:Fault>
            <env:Code>
                <env:Value>rpc:ProcedureNotPresent</env:Value>
            </env:Code>
            <env:Reason>
                <env:Text>Procedure not present</env:Text>
            </env:Reason>
        </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

If I change the xmlns url from `https://ecommerce.app/api/soap/web/all?services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1` to `https://ecommerce.app/api/soap/web/all` everything works fine and my `customerCustomerRepositoryV1SaveRequest` method gets called.

I need the xmlns url to have the `?services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1` part, but I can't figure out how to get it working with it.

I have tried adding `services` and `customerCustomerRepositoryV1` as methods in my webservices class, but that didn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.